# Iterating through list of images, using fallback if one is not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in a CSV file - Columns A and C with the former containing item numbers and the latter images that may or may not have the same item number. **I want the matching image to appear adjacent in column B**.

Images come in a few different forms based on size, first choice is an image ending with "-ROOM.jpg"  followed by an image ending with "-5.jpg" and then "-6.jpg" If I can't find the first type, I'd like to fall back onto "-5.jpg" and then "-6.jpg" using a conditional statement.

Here is what the first few rows appear as:

[image]

```
| SKU         |   | image                |
|-------------|---|----------------------|
| SHS211A-9   |   | SG140B-3.jpg         |
| SHS211A-8   |   | SG140E-4R-FLOOR2.jpg |
| SHS211A-6SQ |   | SG140E-5.jpg         |
| SHS211A-6   |   | SG140E-6R-FLOOR.jpg  |
| SHS211A-5   |   | SG140E-6R-ROOM.jpg   |
| SHS211A-3   |   | SG140E-8-ROOM.jpg    |
| SHS211A-28  |   | SG140E-8.jpg         |
| SHS211A-26  |   | SG140E-4R-FLOOR1.jpg |
| SHS211A-24  |   | SG140E-4R-FLOOR2.jpg |
| SHS211A-2   |   | SG140G-4R.jpg        |
| SHS211A     |   | SG140G-5-FLOOR.jpg   |
```

I've tried this but it doesn't check for the image types (very unfamiliar with VBA):

```
Sub Adrift()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = Cells(I, "A").Value
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(Cells(J, "C").Value, v) > 0 Then
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, I want to match the SKU and then look to see if there is a ROOM matching that SKU and if not use 5, 6 and 4 as fallbacks. I hope that makes sense and if that's too much to ask no problem, I will have to brush up on VBA language reference. Thanks!

Comment: So, what would be the expected answer for the above?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me. Thank you for the edit! The correct answer would be SHS211A-8 to have **SHS211A-8-ROOM.jpg** adjacent to it. That image is further down in the CSV file but once iterated over column C it would find and match it based on column A values. If the ROOM image didn't exist we would like for an image that matches the size ("-8.jpg") and if that doesn't exist we resort to finding anything that matches the item part ("SHS211A"). Hopefully that's not confusing, it's quite cumbersome and will need to expanded upon. I just need some direction.

Comment: I would read into an array then loop that. I would however use Select Case True then each of the preferential matchings (case InStrRev ... > 0 ), in order, as cases inside your double loop. You can then populate the middle "column" of the array when a case is matched and write whole thing back out to sheet in one go.

Comment: I'm going to do some research (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel) I appreciate the tips.

Comment: I'd actually use Right to ensure string ends with rather than contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following might work, where I read into an array then loop rows and last column, checking whether last column starts with what is in current outer row column 1, and ends with either of desired strings. I don't know whether you wish to handle case sensitivity and potential whitespace..... You could probably refactor to simplify a bit.

Assumes same length for A and C. If C is longer then use "C" in `arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)`. If A is longer code is fine as is.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), r As Long, c As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

        For c = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
 
            Select Case True

            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 9) = "-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 9) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For
            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-5.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For
            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-6.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For

            End Select
   
        Next

    Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an excellent start, thank you! I think I'm gonna try to do it in PHP myself as I don't feel like familiarizing myself with VBA since I don't know it very well. I will accept shortly because you've been very helpful.

Comment: When you get a chance, please contact me at ahdrift@protonmail.com - the solution will require 3 or 4 more cases in the `Select Case True` statement, but am willing to pay up to $50 for a complete solution and would like to learn for myself since I don't use much VBA. Let me know if you're interested, thank you.

Comment: No exchange of money required. Happy to help. You have enough rep to open a room to work on solution on here. The conversation will ofc be kept for "all" time :-)